# How to send parameters to a bash script from my web application and then take its result to render it in the browser

Tags: php, bash, shell, cgi, shell-exec

I am using shellinabox terminal to integrate it into my web application. In fact, I want every user that connects to my application to be able to connect to its machine (I already have their IPs addresses). for that I want to put a button, and when the user clicks on it then I send the IP address as a parameter ($param) to a script. and then the script will take this parameter, and try to launch shellinabox in CGI mode to connect to its remote host.

Here is my script code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ssh.sh
# This is a CGI script that uses shellinabox in CGI mode.

function connect {
shellinaboxd --cgi -c /var/lib/shellinabox -s /:SSH:$parm
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
echo "$res" > /tmp/1.log
cannot_connect
fi
}
function cannot_connect {
 printf 'Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n'
 cat <<EOF
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>SSH Shell</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <h1>SSH Shell</h1>

     <p>Unable to establish connection with $parm</p>
   </body>
 EOF
 }

 case "${REQUEST_METHOD}" in
 GET)
 # Retrieve CGI parameter, then start shellinabox with this address
 parms=`echo $QUERY_STRING`
 if [ "$parm" != "" ]; then
    connect $parm
 else
    default
 fi
 ;;

 *)
 default
 ;;
 esac
```

and the principle of what my php file does is just take the result of the script and render it in the browser:
    a little bit like (of cause not just this !!)

```
  $message=shell_exec("/var/www/html/shellinabox.sh 2>&1");
  print_r($message);
```

However I don't know how to pass the parameter ($param) to the script and how to say to the php to render it correctly, after the script returns the result .

Could you please help me do that ?

Comment: Try to pass var to bash like that `$message=shell_exec("/var/www/html/shellinabox.sh $param 2>&1");` And then in bash script use it as `parm="$1"`

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I'm looking for a way to properly do that since I saw that people are using GET and POST methods in their scripts. Moreover, I also don't know if we can properly render the html result to the user at the end (which is a terminal in fact) more properly than with print_r